# Angularjs How to Load service data after inserting a new record?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am working on insertion of users records.After insertion i need to show that record instantly.This is my `js` code for insertion of records.New user creation and showing users list working fine but it shows new inserting records after refreshing the page.

To get all users records from service.

```
var users = this;

    /***********ADD A USER(TAG INPUT)************/
       users.init = init;
        function init(){
            getMyDoers();
        }


    if(localStorageService.get('usersOpen') !== null){
        users.usersDoers = localStorageService.get('usersOpen');
    }
    else
    {
        users.usersDoers = [];
    }
    localStorageService.set('usersOpen', users.usersDoers);
    localStorageService.bind($scope, 'usersOpen');

    users.init = init;
    function init(){
        getMyUsers();
    }
    users.getMyUsers = getMyUsers;  

    function getMyUsers(){  
        //$scope.data = [];
        DataService.getMyUsers().then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data.results;
            $scope.usersOpen.length = 0;
            $scope.usersOpen.push({'data': response.data.results});
        },function errorCallback(response) {

            }
        );

    }   

Js to create users.

$scope.createUser = function()
    {

        console.log($scope.UserID.join());
        $scope.userData = 'userIds='+$scope.UserID.join();
        DataService.createUser($scope.userData).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log('created');

        },function errorCallback(response) {

            }
        );
    }


<ul>

<li ng-repeat="getMyUsers in UsersOpen[0].data track by $index"> 
    <div class="list_left"> 
        <div class="pro_img">
            <img src="images/user.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="pro_text">
            <h2 class=""><a>{{ getMyDoers.firstName }}</a></h2>
            <p class="">Apple, Book, Designer, Web developer</p>
            <span><img src="images/location.png" alt=""/>New York, USA</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using local storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling your 'Angular service' function `getMyUsers()`, immediately after you successfully create a user from `$scope.createUser()` since, function `getMyUsers()` updates your angular model '`UsersOpen`', which could dynamically update your view.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call "getMyUsers" function after inserting new records as shown below : 
As "getMyUsers" function is updating the model UsersOpen , newly added record will be included in the updated "UsersOpen" object.

```
$scope.createUser = function()
{
    console.log($scope.UserID.join());
    $scope.userData = 'userIds='+$scope.UserID.join();
    DataService.createUser($scope.userData).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('created');
        getmyUsers();
    },function errorCallback(response) {

        }
    );
}
```

Comment: It calls the function but does not refresh the records.not shows new inserted record.

Comment: Check the variable "usersOpen". You have defined it as "usersOpen" in controller and used it as "UsersOpen" in html. And why are you repeating it as "getMyUsers in .."  in "getMyUsers in UsersOpen[0].data track by $index" ?

Comment: I am getting the last inserting record in response when i call this function getmyUsers() but it is not showing it in html records.